# Is it possible to change the order of integration in this double integral $\int_0^1 \int_1^x \frac {x^m}{t} dtdx?$

Tags: calculus, integration

Is it possible to change the order of integration in this double integral
$$\int_0^1 \int_1^x \frac {x^m}{t} dtdx?$$
When I graph it the regions have no intersection, so I'm wondering how it can be done.

Comment: Fix some $x$ in $(0,1)$. How is the integral $$\int_1^x f(t)\; dt$$ defined? Is it *minus* the integral on the interval $(x,1)$?

Comment: Your limits of integration mean $1\leq t\leq x$, and  $0\leq x\leq 1$. The only possibility for this is when $x=t=1$ so the integral is $0$. Is it a typo?

Comment: @Taladris: the standard definition is that the value of the integral is the negative of the correct orientation.

Comment: @Clayton that could create plenty of confusion if integrating a positive function can give a negative result, or if (after reversing the orientation and then swapping the order of integration) the integral is over the region $0 < t < x < 1$ in some sense done backwards.  You may as well say $\int_{x=0}^1 \int_{t=1}^x \frac {x^m}{t} dt\, dx = \int_{t=1}^0 \int_{x=0}^t \frac {x^m}{t} dx\, dt$ or  $=\int_{t=0}^1 \int_{x=t}^0 \frac {x^m}{t} dx\, dt$, neither of which are particularly enlightening.

Comment: @Henry: regardless of whether it is confusing or not, a great many introductory calculus textbooks write $\int_b^a f(x)\,dx=-\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to change the order of integration.

Defining the indicator function $\phi(t,x) :=\begin{cases}1, & t \geqslant x\\0, &t < x \end{cases}$ we have
$$I =\int_0^1 \int_1^x \frac {x^m}{t} \,dt\,dx= -\int_0^1 \left( \int_x^1\frac {x^m}{t}\right)\, dt \, dx = -\int_0^1 \left( \int_0^1\frac {x^m}{t}\phi(t,x)\, dt\right) \, dx$$

Applying the Fubini / Tonelli theorem and changing the order of integration we get

$$I = -\int_0^1 \left( \int_0^1\frac {x^m}{t}\phi(t,x)\, dx\right) \, dt= -\int_0^1 \left( \int_0^t\frac {x^m}{t}\, dx\right) \, dt\\= \int_0^1 \frac{t^m}{m+1}\, dt = -\frac{1}{(m+1)^2}$$

---

Integrating in the original order we get

$$I = -\int_0^1 x^m \left(\int_x^1 \frac{dt}{t}\right) \, dx = \int_0^1 x^m \log x \, dx = -\frac{1}{(m+1)^2}$$

Verified [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+of+x%5Em+log%28x%29+dx++from+0+to+1).